# Drupal 7 very slow due to cache clearing at each page

Tags: caching, drupal

I don't know exactly why my drupal 7 website became suddenly slow last week, after few days in production.

With xhprof, i see that at each page load,the  system_list_reset() function triggers a call to cache_clear_all() function.

I deactivated all cache features.

I've read that it may due to missing files in modules and/or themes, but I didn't find missing files (except a wrong issue in 'missing module message fixer' module that indicates a missing module in view_export sub-module of view module).

I manually searched them , I didn't find where drupal can list these missing files.

Or maybe it's due to another problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Open page inspector of your browser and in network tab check what files have unusually long loading time. It maybe be that some external service is causing this. Also it can be that your site is hacked...

Check most banal reason, the storage space - maybe disc of your server is full?

Check if file paths drupal is using are writable. Go to `Configuration -> Median -> File system` and just click Save. If some path is not writable it will get red outline.

Go to `Reports -> Recent log message` and check if some issue is maybe logged there. Also check for web server/php logs.

Try updating modules and drupal core - maybe some bug caused that and it's hopefully fixed in module update.

If not, try disabling modules one by one and see will that still happen. If you don't find problematic module try the same method with your theme. Would be good not to try this in production development and/or make backup before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, 
by disabling module one by one, and by "datamining" in drupal DB, i've found that ADVAGG module was guilty.

The clean was difficult, because some entires remains in some tables of Drupal DB afther the module removing, but I hope it Ok.

BEWARE OF ADVAGG MODULE !

Funny :-/ with 'top', I've found a mining soft in /var/tmp/
systemd-private-a5422b1e6694466bbb0b63203573cad1-apache2.service-jMBN4U : nullcrew (from https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig)

I will investigate how it could land on my webserver

Best regards,